# Is there a way to create a relationship graph in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have data about the relationship between each element in a set as seen in the table below:

[image: table]

Is there a way to create a relationship graph from this data as shown in the below illustration?

[image: relationship graph]

Comment: No there is not any graph that looks even close to what you are seeking. There may be something in PowerBI, and you can download the desktop version for free.

Comment: For future viewers, this tool is useful: https://eiranling.github.io/json-to-graph/

Answer (score 1):

Excel doesn't have a native capability for that type of chart.  However, depending on how much work you want to put in, an XY/Scatter chart can display almost anything-it's simply a series of connected points (series).  The work is usually in making a sensible data layout is consistent for data entry.

Another Excel approach would be to use one of [Mike Bostock's solutions](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock).  He's a wizard for visualizations and if you're comfortable with VBA, you can probably hack something together (I use his sankey diagram solution).  Somewhere on his site he has a demo Excel workbook with several of his visualizations to play with.  You can also find a [D3 example on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983023/d3-js-charts-in-excel/49069480).  And if you want to support D3 integration into Excel, please [vote here](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/10360026-integrate-the-d3-js-visualisation-library-into-exc).